# Where should i add the Google API key when i try to get gps coordinates by address?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, geometry

I think i added my maps google api key to the wrong place. Please help me:

The relevant api key also updated on resources:

```
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaSyAzSgqQEZ..........KMsLlN4</string>


 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response;
            try {
                String address = strings[0];
                HttpDataHandler http = new HttpDataHandler();

                String url = String.format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=AIzaSyAzSgqQEZS1K1...........KMsLlN4", address);

            response = http.getHTTPData(url);
                return response;
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

I don't get any results, i think my access still denied...
Where should i put it?

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=`YOUR API KEY`"

Comment: did you try this url in browser and get any result ? if not did you enable the api from google cloud console ?

Comment: Hi, i get  "This API project is not authorized to use this API." error, but when i checked in console panel i see NONE restrictions

Answer (score 0):

from the official documentation->

`got to the gradle.properties file and add a value with name
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY="your api key"
and rebuild project.After in your manifest file you will see api key.`

P.S don`t forget about permissions

Comment: ``<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>``

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to enable Geocoding API in Google Api console and restrict to specific app!!!